# Share Heroku postgresql with desktop app

Tags: django, heroku, python-3.5, desktop-application, heroku-postgres

I am using Heroku Postgresql in django(Python framework) app but now a days i am working on a desktop version of my application using same language that is Python. So,

> How can i connect my desktop(Python app) to heroku postgesql database.

Or any other best option is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the postgresql credentials with the following command:

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
```

Then, all you have to do is configure your desktop app to use those credentials.

**however** this is not something I would recommend doing. Heroku may need to move your database to another host at any moment.
You could also want to [rotate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials) those credentials. In any of these cases, your desktop app would stop working.

If, instead, you setup an API in your web app, serving JSON (or XML) instead of HTML, you can then consume that data in your desktop app.

Doing so has many advantages, amongst the following:

- You can implement your own authentication mechanism, not having to rely on a single set of credentials for all installations.
- If the database credentials change, you don't need to update all the installations of your desktop app.
- You can show only part of the data to the desktop app.